# iText - crop a specific part of pdf and place it on another pdf's specific position

Tags: java, pdf, itext, crop

I have cropped a pdf file but when i try to place the cropped pdf's page on another pdf file it shows the full page not the cropped part.

Can anyone help me to place the cropped pdf on another pdf file.I have used following code for cropping.

```
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(src);         

        int n = reader2.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfDictionary pageDict;
        PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(305, 152,  532 , 227); //3.15 x 1.04 in inch
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            pageDict = reader2.getPageN(i);
            pageDict.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect);
        }
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader2, new FileOutputStream(src2));

        stamper.close();
        reader2.close();
```

Comment: Setting the crop box doesn't change any of the content. It just changes the visible area when opening the document in a PDF viewer. Importing pages into another (or a new) document, won't take into account the `/CropBox`; you'll see the whole page using the dimensions of the `/MediaBox`. Why don't you change the boundaries of the `PdfImportedPage` instead of first changing the `/CropBox`?

Comment: Actually i don't know how to change the boundary of @PdfImportedPage. Though i searched throughout the iText book. Plz help me out to get a clean crop of the source pdf. It will be really helpful if you give me one simple code for changing the boundary. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If by "iText book", you are referring to iText in Action - Second Edition, then you should read pages 344-347.